# How can I get xaml hot reload to work for custom types in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui, hot-reload

I am using the ReactiveUI library within my WPF project and it seems that 
`ReactiveUserControl<TViewModel> : UserControl` and the  `ReactiveWindow<TViewModel> : Window`
don't work with the `XAML Hot Reload`.

Although extending directly from a `Usercontrol` did allow me to use the `XAML hot reload`.

I can not find any documentation or posts on the matter besides this [one page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2019) which explains absolutely nothing.
Wondering if it maybe has to do with the `x:TypeArguments="navigation:MainVM"` that you have to pass in or the `ReactiveUI` library messing something up internally?

I am using `visual studio 2019` but the same problem occurs on `visual studio 2017`, besides that I am using `.NET Framework 4.6.1` and `ReactiveUI` version 9.20.1.

Comment: I've barely used those reactive usercontrols or windows and back then there was no hot reload. XAML expects to work with parameterless constructors. If you don't have those then that could be your problem.  I don't find it all that useful but I thought hot reload would work with just the control you edit. The textbox or whatever you're changing a property on.

Comment: It seems that any control used inside the view of one of those controls (Textboxes, labels, etc) will not update but putting another normal usercontrol in there and then making changes in that will. If they were managed separately per control, wouldn't that mean that the other controls would also update? It seem as though it only really has the behavior within the xaml of specific types.

Comment: Sounds like it's reloading the parent control  the designer is showing.

Comment: Hi Lloyd, sorry you're having this problem. I am the PM that owns this feature in Visual Studio, i'd love to see if this is still a problem for you and if you possibly have a repro for us to test. We'd love to get this resolved if we can reproduce the issue. If you're willing to please contact me over email? My email is first.last at microsoft.com