# How to debug XAML hot reload in a .Net Core 3.1 WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hot-reload

I have a small WPF test harness application for visualizing user controls that are contained in a separate library. Both projects are netcoreapp3.1 and contained in the same active solution in VS 2019 16.4 on Win10 x64.

The constructor of MainWindow.xaml in the (vanilla) test harness looks as follows:

```cs
namespace HotReloadDemo.TestHarness
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Content = new HotReloadDemo.MainAppUnderTest.MyUserControl();
        }
    }
}
```

The control being tested looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="HotReloadDemo.MainAppUnderTest.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50">This is a test</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In this setup, Hot Reload *works great* - I can make layout changes to the control, and the layout changes. However, in my own (non-demo) solution, the same setup does not seem to work. The app being debugged indeed says "Hot Reload Available", but alas, making changes to the layout of the control does NOT update the live app.

I've looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507878/how-can-i-get-xaml-hot-reload-to-work-for-custom-types-in-wpf) but couldn't find anything that has helped. How can I debug what's going on?

Comment: Thank you for working with our engineers to unblock your real project, I hope things are working now and if you can confirm here that would be great to close to loop with what solution worked for you :)

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help. A little belated, but will do.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a custom build configuration defined ("DebugNoAuth"), and the default implicit behavior is only configured to work with "Release" and "Debug." Explicitly adding XamlDebuggingInformation==true explicitly to the .csproj properties solved the issue.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
... 
    <XamlDebuggingInformation>True</XamlDebuggingInformation> 
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;DebugNoAuth</Configurations>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DebugNoAuth</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Thanks to Dmitry and Evgeny on the Microsoft team for helping debug the debugger.